# Custom post meta box as a sub form

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, post-meta

I have a custom post type with meta boxes existing already.

I'm in need of a feature which would be called a sub-form in the MS Access word. It's section 2 in the below image:

[image]

I have one row of post meta fields already, and I need a way to allow the user to add as many "rows" of those fields as they want:

[image]

I could hack together some javascript which changes the name attribute of those fields, and add some previous and next arrows, but I hope something is readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is not worrying about reloading the page.

I have one row of `input` tags, with a `select` tag on top that I use to navigate rows. On change, the page reloads. Server side, the select box acts as an index for the `input` tag names and post meta.